# Unnamed pipe doesn't work in my code

Tags: c, pipe

I got some weird output:

```
Read 0 bytes: P
?\?
```

from my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char phrase[0] = "stuff this in your pipe and smoke it";
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd[2], bytesRead;
    char message[100];
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    pipe(fd);
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], phrase, strlen(phrase) + 1);
        close(fd[1]);
    }else {
        close(fd[1]);
        bytesRead = read(fd[0], message, 100);
        printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", bytesRead, message);
        close(fd[0]);

    }
}
```

I don't know where I goes wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> pid = fork();
> pipe(fd);
> ```

This example works when child processes inherit descriptors from the parent. You'll want to call `pipe` **before you `fork`**.

Answer (score 2):

@cnicutar already answered one issue. Another problem is:

```
 char phrase[0] = "stuff this in your pipe and smoke it";
```

declares a 0-length array and you are storing a string which is much longer.

Change it to:

```
char phrase[] = "stuff this in your pipe and smoke it";
```

C standard mandates that size of an array should be greater than zero.

**From C99, 6.7.5.2:**

> If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array),
>   the  expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a
>   constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.